# Visual Modelling SDK VS 2013 - MinimalLanguage template does not run

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dsl-tools

If I create the basic example using the MinimalLanguage template in VS2013 it does not run when debugging in the Exp Instance. When I open Sample.mydsl1 it fails on line 234 of CommandSet.cs, with error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object".

Doing exactly the same in VS2012 works fine.

Any suggestions as to what is wrong and how this can be fixed for VS2013?

Can someone with VS2013 (prof) try the Extensibility MinLang template and let me know if it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it was a problem with my VS2013 installation. A repair of it (before adding Update 1) appears to have cleared the isse.